# ActiveRecord most performant way to check if associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the models venues and venue_managers. I need to display all the venues but ordered by whether they have a venue manager.

I could set something up like a "counter cache", but a boolean, on the venue model so I don't have to query the associated venue_managers. I'm wondering if anyone knows a simpler way to check for existence of an associated object without having to issue a sql query?

Edit:

It's a HABTM relationship, so Rail's counter_cache apparently does not work here.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a counter cache 'venue_managers_count' to 'venues' would be the most performant approach.

You can create a scope in Venue:

```
scope :with_managers, -> { where('venue_managers_count > 0') }
```

And query the Venues like this:

```
venue_with_managers = Venue.with_managers
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's a HABTM relationship. Apparently Rail's native counter_caching can't be done. (sorry I should have mentioned that, going to edit my question)

Comment: Change it to a has_many through, and use a counter cache from the intermediate model. A counter is more efficient and safer than a boolean for updating on deletion of the child record, as no other child records need to be queried to test whether the boolean should be set to false -- you just decrement the counter.